# How do I stop SQL splitting string literals when I press Enter in DataGrip or IntelliJ Database Editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

When my cursor is after an open quote in a SQL statement in an IntelliJ database console and I press Enter, it closes the quote on the current line and adds a concatenation symbol with an open quote on the newline.

I disabled formatting the SQL code style settings but that didn't fix it for me.

```
UPDATE blah SET blah2 = 'something<pressed enter>' ||
  '<argh!>...';
```

Is there a way to disable this autoformatting?

Comment: Actually this only occurs if you have already closed the quote and you press enter in the middle somewhere.

Comment: Same issue as https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207738845-enter-newline-in-string-literal

Comment: Related feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/splitting-lines-with-string-literals.html - there doesn't seem to be a setting to change this :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2938) was addressed in [2017.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) version, as a result, **Insert string concatenation on Enter** setting was added specifically for SQL:
[image: Insert string concatenation on Enter]

Answer (score 1):

This can be archived since IntelliJ 13. You simply need to wrap your code with

```
// @formatter:off

your code goes here

// @formatter:on
```

Since IntelliJ Idea 15-16(pardon if i'm wrong), you can also make permanent set up by *Preferences > Editor > Code Style* option

Hope it helps

Comment: doesn't work - i did try disabling sql formatting.  my guess is that this is a setting outside of Editor > Code Style > SQL.  For whatever reason, this doesn't occur in my DataGrip but does occur in IntelliJ.

Comment: just to clarify, this occurs in both datagrip and intellij - it occurs when i've already closed the quote and i press enter somewhere in the middle.

Comment: also this happens in sql console so i can't just rename it to text file.