# IntelliJ inserts ' || ' upon creating new line in sql file

Tags: intellij-idea

In sql file no matter I do when I hit `ENTER` key I always get `' || '` inserted into the file. How to stop IDE doing it?

Comment: "No matter what", or only when the cursor is within a WHERE clause?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, when cursor is inside of  `insert into table (key, text)
values (HERE)` I need it to stop.

Comment: If it's doing that, it thinks you're inside a string, so it's introducing a string continuation. Frankly, that's *correct* behavior, because adding a literal newline is illegal syntax if you're inside a string literal. Check that you don't have stray or unbalanced quotes somewhere in your file.

Comment: You may disable "Insert string concatenation on enter" option in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys | SQL"

Comment: Its IDEA' settings. Check below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864012/how-do-i-stop-sql-splitting-string-literals-when-i-press-enter-in-datagrip-or-in/42869558#42869558